# Replace quotes with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am migrating from Access to SQL Server. There are Excel workbooks connected to the Access DB with ADO. They are not all equal so replacing modules is not possible.

I am trying to find and replace the connection.

I want to replace strings that have quotes inside to reference another declared variable.
For example replace the VBA string
"Data Source= " & Path & Filename
with
"Data Source= " & Data_source & "Initial Catalog= " & Initial_catalog

I was thinking to replace the quotes in the string with @ and then back again to ", but this is not possible for the FIND WHAT as you can see below and not really efficient. I define the Data source and initial catalog in another macro.

The complete code:

```vb
Sub ReplaceTextInCodeModules()

' Must add a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3"
' Also must set "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
' See the url below for more info on these.
' Based on code found at:
' Source: www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx Copyright 2013, Charles H. Pearson

Dim theWorkbook As Workbook
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim numLines As Long ' end line
Dim lineNum As Long
Dim thisLine As String
Dim message As String
Dim numFound As Long

Const FIND_WHAT1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; "
Const REPLACE_WITH1 As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
                  
Const FIND_WHAT2 As String = "@Data Source= @ & Path & filename & @;@"
Const REPLACE_WITH2 As String = "@Data Source= @ & Data_source & @ Initial Catalog= @ & Initial_catalog & @ Integrated Security=SSPI; @"

numFound = 0

For Each theWorkbook In Application.Workbooks
    If theWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        If theWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
            Set VBProj = theWorkbook.VBProject
            For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
                'Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
                Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

                With CodeMod
                    numLines = .CountOfLines
                    For lineNum = 1 To numLines
                        thisLine = .Lines(lineNum, 1)
                        If InStr(1, thisLine, FIND_WHAT1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            message = message & theWorkbook.Name & " | " & VBComp.Name & " | Line #" & lineNum & vbNewLine
                            .ReplaceLine lineNum, Replace(thisLine, FIND_WHAT1, REPLACE_WITH1, , , vbTextCompare)
                            numFound = numFound + 1
                        End If
                        If InStr(1, thisLine, FIND_WHAT2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            message = message & theWorkbook.Name & " | " & VBComp.Name & " | Line #" & lineNum & vbNewLine
                            .ReplaceLine lineNum, Replace(thisLine, FIND_WHAT2, REPLACE_WITH2, , , vbTextCompare)
                            numFound = numFound + 1
                        End If
                        
                    Next lineNum
                End With
            Next VBComp
        End If
    End If
Next theWorkbook

Debug.Print "Found: " & numFound
If message <> "" Then
    Debug.Print message
End If
If numFound = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Nothing found to replace.")
Else
    MsgBox ("Paths replaced!" & vbNewLine & message)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that the string to be replaced looks (**in code line**) like  "Data Source= " & Path & Filename? Isn't it `Data Source=  & Path & Filename`? And the replacement looks to not have any meaning... How does it exactly looks in code? Something like ` Data Source =  & Data_source & "Initial Catalog = " & Initial_catalog`? I know how to handle such a replacement, but I need to exactly know how the two strings look, or have to look **in code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not try clarifying the questions in my comment...

It is late in my country and I will close my laptop. Please, see the next testing code showing how to treat the strings to be replaced, for both cases treated in my comment:

```
Dim x As String, y As String, z As String, w As String
  Dim xx As String, yy As String
  
  x = "Data Source=  & Path & Filename"
  y = "Data Source=  & Data_source & ""Initial Catalog= "" & Initial_catalog"
  z = """Data Source=""  & Path & Filename"
  w = """Data Source=""  & Data_source & ""Initial Catalog= "" & Initial_catalog"
  Debug.Print x 'how the strings looks in the code lines:
  Debug.Print y
  Debug.Print z
  Debug.Print w
  Debug.Print
  xx = "abcd xyz " & x & " 12345678"
  Debug.Print "Replace1 = " & Replace(xx, x, y) 'the string containing the replacement
  yy = "xxxxwwww45 " & z & " aaaabbbb"
  Debug.Print "Replace2 = " & Replace(yy, z, w) 'the string containing the replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks FaneDuru,

It worked, three quotes worked. My target was to replace the cn.open statement.
I even made it more fancy by writing the output to a listbox on a sheet:

```
  If InStr(1, thisLine, FIND_WHAT, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                           message = theWorkbook.Name & " | " & VBComp.Name & " | Line #" & lineNum & " | Connection1"
                           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Replace").ListBox1.AddItem message
                                .ReplaceLine lineNum, Replace(thisLine, FIND_WHAT, REPLACE_WITH, , , vbTextCompare)
                                numFound = numFound + 1
                            End If
```